# Is there a way to associate a Command with a WPF Toolkit DataGridHyperlinkColumn?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, command, wpftoolkit

Is there any way I can associate a Command with a DataGridHyperlinkColumn?  I've tried this:

```
   <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Client Name" Binding="{Binding ShortName}">
     <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
       <Setter Property="Hyperlink.Command" 
                                    Value="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToClientCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ClientsSummaryView}}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Hyperlink.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

At runtime, I can see that the binding is being correctly evaluated (the property getter for the Command is called), but the Command is not executed when I click the hyperlink.  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you sure the command is being associated with the hyperlink?  I tried setting this up in a sample app, and the command wasn't being associated with the hyperlink (if you return false from `CanExecute`, you'll be able to quickly determine if it is wired up).

Instead, I created a `DataGridTemplateColumn` to accomplish this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Client Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToClientCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ClientsSummaryView}}}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding ShortName}">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This would get really annoying if you had to create multiple columns.  After cracking open the Toolkit with Reflector, it looks like it is supporting the `TargetName` / `NavigationUrl` paradigm for using the hyperlink.

If you have a scenario where you would require this type of column in many places, I would suggest extending the `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` and adding a Command property.  You could then modify the element returned from `GenerateElement` so that it used your command.

Comment: Abe: thanks.  I was hoping to shortcut around DataGridTemplateColumn, but, honestly, it doesn't look much worse than what I had.  Thanks again!

Comment: Can you explain how the `<Hyperlink Command="{Binding...">` works? It looks very complicated.

Comment: @Dai - this is a `RelativeSource` binding to an `ICommand` property on the `DataContext` of the `ClientsSummaryView` where this column is added. This question asked about these types of bindings, and hopefully will help you understand it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource/84317#84317

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not with the standard `DataGridHyperlinkColumn`. You need to enhance that class a little.

```
public class DataGridHyperlinkColumn : System.Windows.Controls.DataGridHyperlinkColumn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Support binding the hyperlink to an ICommand rather than a Uri
    /// </summary>
    public BindingBase CommandBinding { get; set; }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var result = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);

        if (((TextBlock)result).Inlines.FirstInline is Hyperlink link)
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(link, Hyperlink.CommandProperty, CommandBinding);

        return result;
    }
}
```

After setting up the correct namespace mapping you can then do this:

```
<c:DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Booking" Binding="{Binding Path=ReservationNo}" CommandBinding="{Binding Path=NavigateCommand}" />
```

This assumes that `NavigateCommand` exists on your viewmodel object.