# Access parent DataContext from DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a `ListBox` which binds to a child collection on a ViewModel. The listbox items are styled in a DataTemplate based on a property on the parent ViewModel:

```
<Style x:Key="curveSpeedNonConstantParameterCell">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurveSpeedMustBeSpecified, 
          ElementName=someParentElementWithReferenceToRootDataContext}" 
          Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I get the following output error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 
 'CurveSpeedMustBeSpecified' property not found on 
   'object' ''BindingListCollectionView' (HashCode=20467555)'. 
 BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.CurveSpeedMustBeSpecified; 
 DataItem='Grid' (Name='nonConstantCurveParametersGrid');
 target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); 
 target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

So if I change the the binding expression to `"Path=DataContext.CurrentItem.CurveSpeedMustBeSpecified"` it works, but only as long as the DataContext of the parent user control is a `BindingListCollectionView`. This is not acceptable because the rest of the user control binds to the properties of the `CurrentItem` on the `BindingList` automatically.

**How can I specify the binding expression inside the style so that it works regardless of the parent data context being a collection view or a single item?**

Answer (score 175, accepted):

I had problems with the relative source in Silverlight. After searching and reading I did not find a suitable solution without using some additional Binding library. But, here is **another approach for gaining access to the parent DataContext** by directly referencing an element of which you know the data context. It uses `Binding ElementName` and works quite well, as long as you respect your own naming and don't have heavy reuse of `templates`/`styles` across components:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="level1Lister" ItemsSource={Binding MyLevel1List}>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Content={Binding MyLevel2Property}
              Command={Binding ElementName=level1Lister,
                       Path=DataContext.MyLevel1Command}
              CommandParameter={Binding MyLevel2Property}>
      </Button>
    <DataTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This also works if you put the button into `Style`/`Template`:

```
<Border.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
          <Button Command={Binding ElementName=level1Lister,
                                   Path=DataContext.MyLevel1Command}
                  CommandParameter={Binding MyLevel2Property}>
               <ContentPresenter/>
          </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Border.Resources>

<ItemsControl x:Name="level1Lister" ItemsSource={Binding MyLevel1List}>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Content="{Binding MyLevel2Property}" 
              Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"/>
    <DataTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

At first I thought that the `x:Names` of parent elements are not accessible from within a templated item, but since I found no better solution, I just tried, and it works fine.

Comment: I have this exact code in my project but it's leaking ViewModels (Finalizer not called, Command binding seems to retain DataContext). Can you verify that this issue exists for you as well?

Comment: @Juve this works, but is it possible to do this so that it would fire for all itemscontrols that implement the same template? Name is unique so then we would need a separate template for each, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @Juve disregard my last, I got it to work by using relativesource with findancestor and searching by ancestortype, (so all the same except not searching by name). In my case I repeat use of ItemsControls each one implementing a template so mine looks like this: Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.OpenDocumentBtnCommand}"

Comment: Not working in my case, XAML Binding Failures showed that DataContext was null

Answer (score 55):

You can use `RelativeSource` to find the parent element, like this -

```
Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurveSpeedMustBeSpecified, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:YourParentElementType}}}"
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource) for more details about `RelativeSource`.

Comment: I had to specify `Mode=FindAncestor` for it to work, but this works and is much better in an MVVM scenario because it avoids naming controls. `Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurveSpeedMustBeSpecified, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:YourParentElementType}}}"`

Comment: work like a charm <3 and didn't have to specify the mode , .net 4.6.1

Answer (score 40):

**RelativeSource** vs. **ElementName**

These two approaches can achieve the same result,

***RelativeSource***

```
Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyBindingProperty, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

This method looks for a control of a type Window (in this example) in the visual tree and when it finds it you basically can access it's `DataContext` using the `Path=DataContext....`. The Pros about this method is that you don't need to be tied to a name and it's kind of dynamic, however, changes made to your visual tree can affect this method and possibly break it.

***ElementName***

```
Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyBindingProperty, ElementName=MyMainWindow}
```

This method referes to a solid static `Name` so as long as your scope can see it, you're fine.You should be sticking to your naming convention not to break this method of course.The approach is qute simple and all you need is to specify a `Name="..."` for your Window/UserControl.

Although all three types (`RelativeSource, Source, ElementName`) are capable of doing the same thing, but according to the following MSDN article, each one better be used in their own area of specialty.

[How to: Specify the Binding Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms746695(v=vs.100))

Find the brief description of each plus a link to a more details one in the table on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 20):

I was searching how to do something similar in WPF and I got this solution:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems,Mode=OneWay}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton 
            Content="{Binding}" 
            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CustomCommand, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,      
                        AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}} }"
            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

I hope this works for somebody else. I have a data context which is set automatically to the ItemsControls, and this data context has two properties: `MyItems` -which is a collection-, and one command 'CustomCommand'. Because of the `ItemTemplate` is using a `DataTemplate`, the `DataContext` of upper levels is not directly accessible. Then the workaround to get the DC of the parent is use a relative path and filter by `ItemsControl` type.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that a DataTemplate isn't part of an element its applied to it.

this means if you bind to the template you're binding to something that has no context.

however if you put a element inside the template then when that element is applied to the parent it gains a context and the binding then works

so this will not work

```
<DataTemplate >
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="projects" Source="{Binding Projects}" >
```

but this works perfectly

```
<DataTemplate >
    <GroupBox Header="Projects">
        <GroupBox.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="projects" Source="{Binding Projects}" >
```

because after the datatemplate is applied the groupbox is placed in the parent and will have access to its Context

so all you have to do is remove the style from the template and move it into an element in the template

**note** that the context for a itemscontrol is the item not the control
ie ComboBoxItem for ComboBox not the ComboBox itself in which case you should use the controls ItemContainerStyle instead

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can solve it using the `ElementName=Something` as suggested by Juve.

BUT!

If a child element (on which you use this kind of binding) is a user control which uses the same element name as you specify in the parent control, then the binding goes to the wrong object!!

I know this post is not a solution but I thought everyone who uses the ElementName in the binding should know this, since it's a possible runtime bug.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNiceControl"
             x:Name="TheSameName">
   the content ...
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="AnotherUserControl">
        <ListView x:Name="TheSameName">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MyNiceControl Width="{Binding DataContext.Width, ElementName=TheSameName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to do through `.`. With this opertaor you able to get acces to `Source`. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0#System_Windows_Data_Binding_Path)

> Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current
> source. For example, Text="{Binding}" is equivalent to Text="{Binding
> Path=.}".

For example I like to do in this way (put `DataContext` inside `Tag` and then get acces to **parent** `DataContext`):

**ResourceDictionary.xaml**:

```
<Style x:Key="SomeControl" TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Tag="{Binding .}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Path=Tag.DataContext.SomeName}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource SomeControl}"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      //...
      SomeName = "Your value";
   } 
   public string SomeName { get; set; }
}
```