# Silverlight: Access parent data context from DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I'm using Silverlight 4. I have an `ItemsControl` with a custom `DataTemplate`. From that `DataTemplate`, I would like to bind to something in the `UserControl`'s `DataContext` - not the `DataContext` of a specific element in the items control. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should answer your question : [Access parent DataContext from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404707/wpf-access-parent-datacontext-from-datatemplate/3547707#3547707)

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="level1Lister" ItemsSource={Binding MyLevel1List}>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Content={Binding MyLevel2Property}
              Command={Binding ElementName=level1Lister, Path=DataContext.MyLevel1Command}
              CommandParameter={Binding MyLevel2Property}>
      </Button>
    <DataTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Silverlight. Rosarch are you using WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: Its for silverlight 3 and above http://10rem.net/blog/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-–-ui-element-to-element-binding

Comment: Sorry to respond a bit late, but I was using Silverlight 4.

Comment: Silverlight 4 .. not sure why it isn't working, will have another look