# ICommand implemtation fails silently

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

**Update**

The button I was trying to use, is inside a `<DataTemplate>`, which apparently caused the issue. Once I tried the code on a button outside the the `<ItemsControl>` area, it works. Can anyone tell me, why it does not work in a repeated button like `<ItemsControl>` and `<DataTemplate>`?

I am trying to implement an MVVM communication pattern, based on an article from [TutorialsPoints.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_view_viewmodel_communication.htm). I have modified the code slightly, but over all it is still very similar to the code in the article. What I want to do is, to write a line in the console once a button is clicked.

With my implementation (see code below) nothing happens when I click the button. I have also tried adding a break point in the `OnClick()`  function to see if that is run, this is not the case. However a break point in the constructor of `MyICommand()` shows that the class is actually initialized. What am I doing wrong then?

**The Button**

```
<Button Content="Do stuff!"
        Command="{Binding FakeCommand}"
        Cursor="Hand"
        Background="Red" 
        Foreground="White" 
        BorderThickness="0" 
        Padding="10 0 10 0"  />
```

**The View Model**

```
public class AgreementViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyICommand FakeCommand { get; set; }

    public AgreementViewModel ()
    {
        LoadAgreements();
        FakeCommand = new MyICommand(OnClick, CanClick);
        FakeCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something was clicked...");
    }

    private bool CanClick()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**The Implementation of ICommand**

```
public class MyICommand : ICommand
{
    Action _TargetExecuteMethod;
    Func<bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate {};

    public MyICommand(Action executeMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public MyICommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return _TargetCanExecuteMethod();
        }

        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you tie the ViewModel to the View ? By setting the `DataContext` of the view ?

Comment: @Noceo Where do you expect to see your message? If you write this line to a file, does it work?

Comment: @chester89 I would expect to see it in the output window (it is merely for testing).

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir the view model is tied using the auto hook-up from earlier in the tutorial. This seems to works fine, since everything from the view model is shown in my view.

Comment: Using your code if I hook it up manually it works

Comment: Try `Debug.WriteLine` instead, or just set a breakpoint. I'd also recommend to write `CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` and get rid of the `delegate {}` initialization.

Comment: @Clemens I have tried with a break point, but it is never reached. Also tried with Debug.WriteLine, also no result.

Comment: See the update. The missing action was caused by using the command in a `DataTemplate`

Comment: It sounds more like it was caused by `ItemsControl`, which will introduce a new `DataContext` for each item.

Comment: @grek40 that was indeed the case. Never thought of it that way. I am still lost on how to have a button with a command in each row for an `ItemsControl`, but maybe I will get to that at some point...

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404707/access-parent-datacontext-from-datatemplate is an answer to the magic google search "WPF ItemsControl Binding Parent" ;) Note the linked question might be confusing, but the accepted answer is quite clear

Comment: Side note, calling FakeCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); in the constructor is useless, as databinding is happening long after the vm is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `ItemsControl` (as you mention in the updated version) then the `DataContext` for each instantiation of the `DataTemplate` will each item of the source collection used in the `ItemsSource`. To bind to a command in the parent view model you could use `ElementName` to get to the ItemsControl

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" x:Name="root">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Do stuff!"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.FakeCommand,  ElementName=root}"
                    Cursor="Hand"
                    Background="Red" 
                    Foreground="White" 
                    BorderThickness="0" 
                    Padding="10 0 10 0"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

An alternative if you don't want to use names would be to use `RelativeSource` to get to the items control:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.FakeCommand,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
```

Note that in both cases the data context will be the `ItemsControl`, so you need to do `DataContext.FakeCommand`, `DataContext` refers here to the data context of `ItemsControl`

You might also need the item the command was invoked for since it can be invoked for any item in the source collection. To do that you can add a a `CommandParameter={Binding}`, and the parameter passed the command will be the item (your implementation does not pass the parameter to the delegate, but it could)