# ReactiveUI in WPF: how to bind a command from the parent's ViewModel to a button in ItemsControl.ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

It's the code from [YouIandReactiveUI](https://github.com/kentcb/YouIandReactiveUI/blob/c4bc8328a6faa0d846bb1441a50aeb22ed4bfae0/Host.WPF/Views/Samples/Chapter%2002/Sample%2002/MainView.xaml#L121)

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?
Or is there any way to bind in code with IViewFor?

```xml
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <local:TweetMediaAttachmentView ViewModel="{Binding .}"/>
                            <Button
                                x:Name="removeButton"                                                                
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveAttachmentCommand, ElementName=attachmentsItemsControl}" />                                                            
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem. One solution is to use RelativeSource, as proposed here: [Access parent DataContext from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404707/access-parent-datacontext-from-datatemplate)

Answer (score 0):

Couple different options, all of which would use the `IViewFor` functionality.

First is when using the ReactiveUI's OneWayBind functionality to bind to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, if you don't set a `ItemTemplate` it will search for the associated `IViewfor<View model>`.

Another you can use the ItemTemplate and use ViewModelViewHost control and set the view model. This is almost identical to the first approach.

For the command binding I would pass the command into the view model so you don't have to worry about the data context binding.