# Binding a property with a different ItemSource WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a list bound as ItemSource that contains two strings: Option 1 and option 2, I have 2 text boxes where I bind and display these two options. I also have two radio buttons next to the two textboxes. I want to bind these radiobuttons but every time I click on them nothing happens. I found out the reason for this, because now he is always trying to find the bool in my list whether the button is checked or not. Is there a way to set in the xaml code that I can access the bool property which is in my ViewModel?

ViewModel:

```
public class WortAuswahlViewModel : AntwortMoeglichkeitViewModel, IWortAuswahlViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<AuswahlOptionen> m_auswahlOptionen;
    public WortAuswahlViewModel(WortAuswahl wortAuswahl)
    {
        if (wortAuswahl?.Optionen == null)
        {
            return; 
        }
        m_auswahlOptionen = new ObservableCollection<AuswahlOptionen>(wortAuswahl.Optionen); 
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AuswahlOptionen> WortAuswahlOptionen
    {
        get
        {
            return m_auswahlOptionen;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_auswahlOptionen != value)
            {
                m_auswahlOptionen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool m_isRadioButtonCheckedFirst; 
    public bool CheckButtonEins
    {
        get
        {
            return m_isRadioButtonCheckedFirst;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_isRadioButtonCheckedFirst != value)
            {
                m_isRadioButtonCheckedFirst = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool m_isRadioButtonCheckedSecond;
    public bool CheckButtonZwei
    {
        get
        {
            return m_isRadioButtonCheckedSecond;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_isRadioButtonCheckedSecond != value)
            {
                m_isRadioButtonCheckedSecond = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WortAuswahlOptionen}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Viewbox Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsChecked="{Binding CheckButtonEins}"/>
                            <DockPanel  LastChildFill="True">
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" x:Name="TXT_optionEinsLoesung" Text="{Binding OptionEins}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                                <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsChecked ="{Binding CheckeButtonZwei}"/>
                                <DockPanel  LastChildFill="True">
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" x:Name="TXT_optionZweiLoesung" Text="{Binding OptionZwei}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access parent DataContext from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404707/access-parent-datacontext-from-datatemplate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataContext` of each `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle` inside `ItemsControl` is automatically set to the corresponding element of the `ItemsSource`.

One way to redirect the `DataContext` to somewhere outside of the elements is to start the binding path from the `DataContext` of the root object of your `Window`.

So if your `WortAuswahlViewModel` is set to the `DataContext` of a `Window`, first you need to set the binding source to the `Window` using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}` and then set path to `Path=DataContext.CheckButtonEins`

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.CheckButtonEins}"
```

If your  `WortAuswahlViewModel` is set to the `DataContext` of another UI element, replace `Window` with the type of that element.

Comment: Thanks for your answere. This sadly doesnt work i tried something similar. Maybe its helpful to mention that my View is an UserControl? So maybe i need to set a different AncestorType?

Comment: I solved the problem. The Code worked. I just had to set the AncestorType to "UserControl" now it perfectly worked. Thanks for youre help!