# WPF DataTemplate Show Original Control

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

In a DataTemplate I want to show the Control which is actually replaced by the DataTemplate. With error validation, this is possible by using `<AdornedElementPlaceHolder />`. However, this seems not to work in a normal DataTemplate.

I think there would be a simple solution, but just can't find it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible and here is why. `DataTemplate` doesn't replace anything. Instead, a control that defines a DataTemplate **contains** the content provided by it. If it was possible then there would be an infinite loop (control -> data template -> control -> data template -> ...).

I suggest you read the following article to fully understand data templates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A DataTemplate in some sense "replaces" a *data* object and not a *UI* object - in other words, not a Control. If you are trying to work with properties of the Control (usually either a ContentControl or ItemsControl) that is using the template, try a [RelativeSource Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource) where the AncestorType is the type of the Control.

Comment: What about the ControlTemplate?

Comment: If you set the control template, you are completely replacing the original "look" of the control. I don't know of any way to reference the original template inside of a new one, as it's pretty much a wholesale replacement. Generally the approach people take is to use Expression Blend to "bake out" the standard control template and then modify the fully expanded one to suit their needs. It's clunky, but it works.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. In the error validation template, you can get the original control by '<AdornedElementPlaceHolder />'.

Comment: That's because error validation is using an adorner on top of the existing element. Both data templates and control templates are actually modifying the visual tree itself instead of tacking something in "on top" of the existing visuals.