# Binding IsEnabled to the parent ViewModel instead of the UserControl ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm-light

I developed a user control in SilverLight that contains several child controls. `Textboxes`, `ComboBoxes` and so on.

The problem is, when I include that `UserControl` into a parent view and set the complete control to `IsEnabled=False`, the child controls in that specific `UserControl` are still enabled.

After all I found the problem.

Adding something like that, implies that the `IsEnabled` Binding is located in the `UserControl` binding, not as expected from myself in the `DataContext` of the parent.

```
<localControls:TeamEmployeeSelector Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          IsEnabled="{Binding CanModify}" DataContext="{Binding Confidentiality}"/>
```

**QUESTION:**
But there's still the question how I can bind the `IsEnabled` to the ViewModel of the Parent? Because it's not very elegant to copy the `CanModify` Property to the ViewModel of the Child Control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of modifying a binding in some way (for example you can make it dependent on other control name as it is proposed in other answer) I would move separate the control which will be disabled and control where `DataContext` will be changed. For example:

```
<ContentControl IsEnabled="{Binding CanModify}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <localControls:TeamEmployeeSelector DataContext="{Binding Confidentiality}"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Hi Snowbear, this seems to be a valid solution. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this.

Your `TeamEmployeeSelector` `UserControl` will contain a single root level element which by default is a `Grid` and is given the name "LayoutRoot".

Now you can bind the `IsEnabled` property of all the child elements to the `UserControl` like this:-

```
 <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Parent.IsEnabled, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" ... />
```

By using element-to-element binding you do not need to copy the `CanModify` property in to child view models.

Some might suggest that you simply add an `x:Name` to your UserControl element and then bind directly to it rather than going via the `Parent` property of the root element as I do above.  That'll work ok in Silverlight 4 but not in 3 or WP7.  Personally I prefer the above.

Comment: Hi Anothony, I did not try your solution right now, but it does not seem to solve the problem where the CanModify Property must be located. It's not the problem to disable the child controls of the user control, but to disable the usercontrol itself. This UserControl IsEnabled binding depends on the CanModify Property, which indeed must than be located in the viewmodel of the control. That point anoys me ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue.  Generally, when creating a `UserControl`, you want to set itself as the `DataContext` for its sub-elements.  This is most easily accomplished in the constructor:

```
UserControlExample() {
   InitializeComponent();
   RootElement.DataContext = this;
}
```

Where `RootElement` is the name you give to this first child (usually a Grid or panel) of your `UserControl`.

From here you can set natural bindings for your sub-elements like so:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MainTextBox" IsEnabled={Binding IsEnabled} />
```

This works, since `TextBox` inherits the `DataContext` of the parent layout panel.

Finally, if you want to have your `UserControl`'s `IsEnabled` property to be related to its parent, this is best done at the point of declaration:

```
<Grid>
   <UserControlExample IsEnabled={Binding CanModify} />
</Grid>
```

This way you keep your concerns separate. The sub-controls don't care what the `UserControl` is reflecting. They just need to know how to enable/disable when the control's `IsEnabled` property flips.

```
sub-controls IsEnabled bound to --> (UserControlExample is DataContext)
   UserControlExample.IsEnabled bound to -->  (VM is DataContext)
      VM.CanModify
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible in Silverlight, but in WPF I would use RelativeSource.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource).

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

```
<localControls:TeamEmployeeSelector Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SomeElementName_With_Parent_ViewModel, Path=DataContext.CanModify}" DataContext="{Binding Confidentiality}"/>
```