# Bind to Parent.Parent from DataGridTextColumn.Header

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, icommand

hi normally it should work automatically but it doesn't

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="350" IsReadOnly="True" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding StichwortList}" >
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisplayName}" Width="350">
                      <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <DockPanel Margin="0" Width="340" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True">
                                  <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0" Text="Name"/>
                                  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="-" Margin="0" Width="23" Command="{Binding RemoveStichwortCommand}"/>
                                  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="+" Margin="0" Width="23" Command="{Binding AddStichwortCommand}"/>
                                  <Label />
                            </DockPanel>
                      </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                 </DataGridTextColumn>
           </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

relevant Code:

```
        private RelayCommand _addStichwortCommand;
        public ICommand AddStichwortCommand
        {
            get { return _addStichwortCommand ?? (_addStichwortCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.OnAddStichwort())); }
        }

        private void OnAddStichwort()
        {
            // some code
        }

        private RelayCommand _removeStichwortCommand;
        public ICommand RemoveStichwortCommand
        {
            get { return _removeStichwortCommand ?? (_removeStichwortCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.OnRemoveStichwort())); }
        }
private void OnRemoveStichwort()
        {
           // some code
        }
```

my other bindings to this view works and my Command Binding also works fine normally

so could please anyone tell me whats wrong with my binding?

### Edit

ohh i forgot

it is all in a `Usercontrol` whose `Datacontext` contains al the Propertys andfor the Bindings and Commands

### Soultion:

the `DockPanel` need to Bind his `Datacontext` to the `Usercontrol` `Datacontext` and the `Usercontrol` needs a name

`x:Name="uc"`

```
<DockPanel Margin="0" Width="340" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=DataContext}">
     <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0" Text="Name"/>
     <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="-" Margin="0" Width="23" Command="{Binding RemoveStichwortCommand}"/>
      <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="+" Margin="0" Width="23" Command="{Binding AddStichwortCommand}"/>
      <Label />
</DockPanel>
```

if the solution above doesn't work you should take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84317/1993545)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name your `UserControl` in **XAML** and use it in binding. Something like following code:

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc" >
.
.
.
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="-" Margin="0" Width="23" Command="{Binding RemoveStichwortCommand, ElementName=uc}"/>
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="+" Margin="0" Width="23" Command="{Binding AddStichwortCommand, ElementName=uc}"/>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: remove path and try again.

Comment: same result doesn'Twork and in snoop i doesnt see som binding errors