# How can i pass entire current view through command parameter

Tags: wpf

I hava a User control and in that user control  one button.

On click on that button i need to pass the entire view through command paramter.

How can i pass the view through command paramter?

Comment: Oo - Why would you do that? Have you anything tried so far? One tip `RelativeBinding`.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

If I remember the right way (and you want to bind to your current Window instance), it should be

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

See: [How do I use WPF bindings with RelativeSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource)

Comment: Will provide the datacontext and it will not provide the view details "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Do you want to bind to the view (type of Window / UserControl) or to the DataContext of your view?

Comment: You could also set x:Name="myView" on the View and use {Binding ElementName=myView}. Is easier than RelativeSource, but shouldn't be used if your View is the top level element of a XAML file.