# How to set default time for TimePicker control

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker

In my WPF application, I've used TimePicker control from extended WPF Toolkit. When I run application, TimePicker control should display default value as "12:00 AM". Currently it's showing me blank. How to achieve this result?

Xaml code:

```
<xctk:TimePicker x:Name="StartValue" Value="{Binding StartTimeBinding, 
    ElementName=MainWin, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" 
    Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" 
    EndTime="11:59:0"/>
<xctk:TimePicker x:Name="StopValue" Value="{Binding StopTimeBinding, 
     ElementName=MainWin, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" 
    Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" 
    EndTime="11:59:0"/>
```

`TimePicker` controls bound to below properties:

```
public string StartTimeBinding 
{ 
    set
    { 
        this._id = value;
    } 
    get
    { 
        return this._started_at.ToString("h:mm tt");
    } 
}

public string StopTimeBinding 
{ 
    set
    {
        this._id = value;
    } 
    get
    { 
        return this._ended_at.ToString("h:mm tt");
    } 
}
```

Comment: I assume you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your ViewModel class, Did you ?

Comment: Yes. But what is the relation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface interface with this? Can you explain?

Comment: @Nitesh Even if the OP did, he isn't calling OnPropertyChanged when he sets the value, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

set this property in your view model:

```
 private string _StartShift;
    public string StartShift
    {
        get { return _StartShift; }
        set
        {
            if (_StartShift != value)
            {
                _StartShift = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StartShift");
            }
        }
    }
```

set this property in the contructor to your desired default value:

```
 StartShift = "6:30";
```

xaml code:

```
  <xctk:TimePicker Grid.Row="5"  Grid.Column="1" Width="auto" StartTime="5:00" Value="{Binding StartShift}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn`t it because `TimePicker.Value` is of type `DateTime` and you bind it to `StartTimeBinding` property which is of type `string`? Just get the value, TimePicker will do the formatting:

```
public DateTime StartTimeBinding 
{ 
    set
    { 
        this._id = value;
    } 
    get
    { 
        return this._started_at;
    } 
}
```

**Edit:**
It appears that my advice above does not resolve the issue as `TimePicker` works alright with strings. So my guess it that problem lies in this part: `ElementName=MainWin`. There`s no MainWin element in this context, so the binding can`t find required property. It`s hard to say without seeing whole layout but maybe you can fix it with [RelativeSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `ToString(h:mm tt")` from your properties and change the type to `DateTime`. The `TimePicker` control binds to a `DateTime`,  not a `string`.