# Visibility of a Button in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid with three columns.

There is a delete button in the third column.
Its visibility depends on boolean property called 'ControlsEnabled'.

DataGrid is populated by items in 'ObservableCollection'.

The problem is that 'ControlsEnabled' is not a property of items in our 'ObservableCollection' and it should not be.
'ObservableCollection' is property of another class.

Question: how should I change my XAML description to solve my problem?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=field1}" 
                        Width="140" 
                        Header="head1"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=field2}" 
                        Width="140" 
                        MinWidth="50" 
                        Header="head2"/>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Padding="5" 
                        Click="DeleteButton_Click" 
                        Tag="{Binding}" 
                        Content="X" 
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=ControlsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock>
                            Delete
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is `ControlsEnabled` a property of? Your window?

Comment: Yes, it is a property of my window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Binding RelativeSource. Read [How do I use WPF bindings with RelativeSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource)

For example:

```
{Binding Path=PathToProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}
```

Or use Binding ElementName to jump to specific control data context.

```
<Window ... x:Name="_this">
    <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=DataContext.ControlsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Comment: So if I have object called `xyz.ControlsEnabled` and I want to use it in my example then what should I do?  `xyz` is not related to items in my `ObservableCollection`

Comment: @Jacek Depends what your `DataContext` is, but something like `xyz.ControlsEnabled`

Comment: ControlsEnabled must be accessible though some control DataContext. e.g. if your main ViewModel have property ControlsEnabled and is bind to DataContext of your Window you will need to use my second example.

Answer (score 0):

`ControlsEnabled` should be a property on the `item` that is added to your `ObservableCollection`. That is if you are trying to delete that item from your collection..

Comment: The thing is that I do not want to iterate through all items in `ObservableCollection` and make them all `ControlsEnabled = true` or `ControlsEnabled = false`...