# How would I use a command that binds to a method outside a template?

Tags: c#, xaml

So I have a command on a radio button that binds to a method that's outside of the itemsource (which is a ObservableCollection). This is producing an error
when the radio button is clicked.

**Error:**

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TaskSelectedCommand' property not found on 'object' ''Task' (HashCode=46555789)'. BindingExpression:Path=TaskSelectedCommand; DataItem='Task' (HashCode=46555789); target element is 'RadioButton' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

**Data template XAML Code:**

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Tasks">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                    <RadioButton ToolTip="Start tracker" GroupName="rdoExchange" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,10,1" Command="{Binding TaskSelectedCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    <TextBox ToolTip="Task currently being tracked" IsEnabled="true" Margin="25,15,-375,4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Name}" RenderTransformOrigin="6.033,0.727" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="430,15,-455,4" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Time}"/>
                    </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

**Using the data template on a list box:**

```
    <StackPanel Name="allTaskList" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  Height="171" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="25,10,-523,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="512" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Tasks}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Task.cs code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace Sundial
{
    public class Task
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Time { get; set; }

        public bool Selected { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs Code:**

```
public ICommand TaskSelectedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return mTaskSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                mTaskSelected = value;
            }

        }
public MainWindowViewModel()
        {

            TaskSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(TaskSelected));
            TaskList = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
    }



public void TaskSelected(object obj)
        {

            var task = TaskList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Selected == true);

            if (task != null)
            {
                timer.Start();
            }


        }
public void AddTask(object obj)
        {
            TaskList.Add(new Task() { id = taskNum, Name = "Task", Selected = false, Time = 0.0 });
    }
```

This is not all the code, this is just the code that is in relation to the problem.

Comment: Any ideas to why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your XAML is written, WPF is looking for an object in the visual tree, starting at the `ListBox`, that has a non-null `DataContext` property.  When it finds that object, it binds the `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` property to a property of that object called `TaskList`.  I assume this binding is working, because you have not mentioned that there were any error messages about that binding failing.

Since `TaskList` is bound to the `ListBox's ItemsSource` property, I'm assuming it's a collection.

WPF next loops over all of the objects in the `TaskList` collection and creates a copy of the `DataTemplate` for each one, sticks it in a `ListBoxItem` object, and adds that to the `ListBox's Items` collection.  It is while it builds the copy of the `DataTemplate` that it tries to bind the radio button to the `TaskSelectedCommand` property of the current object in the `TaskList` collection.  It's not finding a `TaskSelectedCommand` property on that this object, so it fails and generates the error message.

You can either create a `TaskSelectedCommand` property on the items in the collection, or you can create one on the object that's got the `TaskList` collection property.  In the first case, you make no changes to your XAML. In the second case, you have to change the binding for the `TaskSelectedCommand` so it's specifies a `RelativeSource`.

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios like this you use a RelativeSource in the declaration of the binding for your command. Have a look at this answer: 
[How do I use WPF bindings with RelativeSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource)