# Bind Property in Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I have the following `HeaderTemplate` for an `Expander`:

```
<Expander.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="#939393">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="border" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" 
                                        Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#FF000000" Margin="1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Background="#6E6E6E"/>
            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Expander}}" Focusable="False">
                <Image Source="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Expander}, Converter={StaticResource boolToExpanderDirectionConverter}}"/>
            </ToggleButton>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="General" Margin="5,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Expander.HeaderTemplate>
```

This Headertemplate I have defined directly at one `Expander`. Now I want to move this Template to a Resource and apply it to all Expanders. My problem now is, that I don't know how to set the Header of the `TextBlock` in the Template to the Header of the `Expander`.

I knwo there's a way with `TemplateBinding`, but unfortunately I don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TemplateBinding** can only be used within a ControlTemplate.TemplateBinding is used for binding to the element properties within the template definition..
>
> here in your example you have used controltemplate for toggleButton.

**Example For** **TemplateBinding**

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            .....
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
    </Style>

<ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="White"/>
```

*Here Border and Contentpresnter will bind  properties of ToggleButton that is alreday defined in its defination.*

---

But in your example you used Datatemplate..so you cant use TemplateBinding ..Please Follow This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource) for Binding Syntax.

**Solution For Your example**

> Using Binding syntax we can bind Header property to different exapnder
> **Text="{Binding Path=Header,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}}"**

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderHeaderTemplate">
        <Grid Background="#939393">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="border" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#FF000000" Margin="1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Background="#6E6E6E"/>
            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Expander}}" Focusable="False">
                <Image Source="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Expander}, Converter={StaticResource boolToExpanderDirectionConverter}}"/>
            </ToggleButton>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Header,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}}" Margin="5,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

 <StackPanel>
    <Expander Header="General1" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderTemplate}"/>
    <Expander Header="General2" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderTemplate}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a idea of Template binding by below code i had implemented this when i was learning XAML.

```
<Button Template="{DynamicResource CircleButton}" Background="Green" Content="1"></Button>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="CircleButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="36" MinWidth="36">
            <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Ellipse>
            <ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontFamily="Calibri" TextBlock.FontSize="24" TextBlock.Foreground="Wheat" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
```

you have to give a  x:Key to control Template and when you are binding it with some specific element define that x:key there like i did Template="{DynamicResource CircleButton}".

following is your case:

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                     // Do your thing.
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

this will apply to all Expander throught your application. You can put this Style into App.xaml file for code cleanness. hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying a HeaderTemplate via a DataTemplate, the DataContext of the template IS the Header. This simple example works:

```
<Expander Header="Test">
    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
</Expander>
```