# Access function of C# from XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have this button in my XAML code-

```
           <Button x:Name="button" 
            Content="{Binding Name}" 
            Click="Start"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="123,45,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I have another C# code-

```
namespace MyGame
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public string Name()
          {

             get{ return "Hello" };
          }
       private void ButtonNo3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

          Button obj = (Button)sender;

          var selectedButton = obj.Content.ToString();
          //This is where I get this error-An exception of type        'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyGame.exe but was not handled in user code
         }
    }
  }
```

My question is how can I get `Content` of my `Button` in my `xaml` code to store the value from the function of `C#` code?

Answer (score 2):

You accomplish this via *binding*. Binding has a couple rules:

- You can only bind to properties
- Those properties must be public
- For the binding to evaluate, the property must be on the View's `DataContext`

That data context is usually a `ViewModel` object instead of the view itself, following the MVVM pattern.

So in your view model, you would have:

```
//Properties (and methods) are PascalCase!
public string Name { get { return "Hello";} }
```

Then once you set the data context, your XAML is:

```
      <Button x:Name="button" 
        Content="{Binding Name}" 
        Click="Start"  
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="123,45,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: Note that there are ways to duck around the `DataContext` restriction by setting the `Source` or `RelativeSource`  - these offer the ability to bind through static values or `DataContext` of other controls

Comment: It is also possible to set the button's data context to the parent MainPage class using a RelativeSource.  Then you could bind to properties in the "code behind" but I would strongly recommend going with a View Model and following the MVVM architecture.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I tried the above implementation.But it is giving me this error-
`An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyGame.exe but was not handled in user code`

Comment: @Coder Trap the exception and do some debugging. Thats not enough information for me to help, and you need to able to debug your NREs anyways :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Sorry But I am still not able to figure it out.I have editted my code above with the error.Also the contents of the Button is not displaying anything.

Comment: @Coder You still need to set the `DataContext`. If you insist on doing so in the code-behind, write `this.DataContext = this` in the constructor (note, this is *terrible* design).

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned the need for syncing, the simplest answer to your question would be to use the `x:Name` identifier and just set the content property from a function in your C# code.

```
button.Content = name();
```

In case your can move your method into a different class, you can also use an `ObjectDataProvider` to wire up your method `name` to the XAML code, and then use data-binding to connect the data provider to your code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="fnName"
                         ObjectType="{x:Type bind:SomeClassHoldingYourMethod}"
                         MethodName="name">
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button x:Name="button" 
        Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource fnName}, Mode=OneTime}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="123,45,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

However if you want a simpler approach and you want your data to be in sync with the UI (so whenever you change something in your data it is reflected on the UI controls automatically) **you can convert your function to a readonly property** and do what @BradleyDotNET suggested.

In general, separating data-binding from actual data, is considered a good thing.

Be aware that in WPF you can always do stuff **declaratively** in XAML, but you can also do the same thing in code **programmatically** using C#. Most people prefer the declarative way, but it's good to know you can do the same (and more) in C# if you need it.

And please, use the [.NET framework naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and name your methods with pascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access methods from XAML, your options are relatively restricted.

The first and most obvious is to use event handlers, which go into the code-behind of your `View` and thus violate MVVM. The can, however, offer the easiest way to execute code. If you are using a `ViewModel`, you can also use `dynamic`  to perform late binding to the desired method - but only from C# code.

```
<Button ...
        Clicked="Button_OnClick"/>
```

and in code-behind

```
public void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (DataContext as dynamic).ButtonClicked;
}
```

Note that while it is possible to use the specific type of `ViewModel` instead of `dynamic`, this would also be a violation of MVVM pattern - and a far worse one than code behind, because it forces your `View` to be used with a particular `ViewModel`.

Another option is to utilize [`Interactions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.interaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) and a [`CallMethodAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.callmethodaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) (from the Expressions Blend SDK).

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ButtonClicked"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:InterAction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: I would contend that all views are made to work with a particular view model. Feel free to decouple via an interface, but to say that `dynamic` is a good solution, let alone the only one, is a bit of a stretch