# Get row value in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My Code is as follows

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
      <ListBox Width="400" Margin="10" x:Name="myListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridVal}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}">
              <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                     <Expander Header="Header1" IsExpanded="True">
                        <StackPanel>
                          <DataGrid
                             x:Name="dataGrid"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridVal}" 
                             Height="250" Width="250" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
  public object CurrentItem
  {
    get{return _item;}
    set{_item=value;}
  }
```

It displays a Listbox which has Expander and a Datagrid

I want to get the current selected row in datagrid which I am not able to get at this point.I am getting Datatemplate items instead of Datagrid

Comment: use raiseonproperty change or onpropertychange RaiseonPropertyChange("CurrentItem"); @kyle

Comment: it seems you're binding to `CurrentItem` for both the list and the `DataGrid`. Are you sure that you are inspecting the correct `CurrentItem`? It should be the one in the class that also has the property `GridVal`

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in the debug output? Could you show your viewmodels that you are using as datacontexts?

Comment: Yes It is `SelectedItem` not `SelectedIndex`..But still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong property to data bind to your `CurrentItem` property. Instead of `SelectedIndex`, you should data bind to the [`DataGrid.SelectedItem` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding GridVal}" Height="250" Width="250" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" />
```

Although, as @Default mentioned, you are also trying to data bind the `CurrentItem` property to two different control properties, so you'll need to add a different property to get this to work properly. Furthermore, the `CurrentItem` property should be of the same type as the items in the `GridVal` collection.

---

UPDATE >>>

You seem to be missing some information as you are also trying to data bind the same collection to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` and the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` which is not possible. Everything inside the `DataTemplate` will automatically have its `DataContext` set to an item from the above mentioned collection, eg. each data item will be set as the `DataContext` in each `DataTemplate` when it is rendered.

Therefore, for your current code to work, your data items in that collection should also have `CurrentItem` and `GridVal` properties, but I'm guessing that they don't. You should also have errors in your Output Window in Visual Studio that clearly tell you that there is no `CurrentItem` property in whatever object type is in your collection.

I suggest that you read through the [Data Templating Overview‎](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to help you better understand the situation.

Comment: Although the second `CurrentItem` is included in the `DataTemplate`, so at least they are not binding to the same `DataContext` (unless that's been modified somewhere outside the code example). However, his explanation does seem to point to that he is inspecting the "parent" property, not the child property.

Comment: @Sheridan Can you explain with example

Answer (score 0):

You can use binding with [Relative source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84317/667792):

```
{Binding Path=PathToProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}
```

Or with specified ElementName:

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.PathToProperty, ElementName=myListBox}
```