# My progress bar inside a list is not updating in wpf application

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I am working on WPF application and have a progress bar for each item inside a ListBox, but when I am binding it to some value its not updating the UI. If I set a specific int value like 45, UI gets updated. Why it is not binding to the value?

Comment: @ManDani thank u so much . Its working i was getting mad over it . Thank u so much.

Comment: for more detail check this very well explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every ListBoxItem has his own DataContext (not the same as the view). If SawStatus is a property of your viewmodel, you have to change your binding to something like

```
Value ="{Binding DataContext.SawStatus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox }"
```

Otherwise you have to give more details about the ItmesSource of your ListBox.

Comment: thank u so much . Its working i was getting mad over it . Thank u so much.