# Different ItemSource within ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Vals, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="SearchCol" Text="{Binding Col}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="SearchText" Text="{Binding Filter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Modules.SelectedModule.Vwr.Table.ExpandBoMCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                     AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding Col}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CTStr}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Update**

I'm close! I've found a way to get my data where it needs to go, now my issue is accessing both pieces of data. Command Parameter can only pass one.

**Update 2**

I passed the entire dataItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work in WPF you have at least couple options:

**Option 1:**

1. Set DataContext for your ItemsControl
2. Bind ItemsControls ItemsSource
3. Give name to your ItemsControl
4. Bind your command using ElementName and Path

For steps 1-3, you can use the following example:

```
<ListView DataContext="{Binding MyVm}" x:Name="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsItemClickEnabled="False">
```

For step 4:

```
<core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=Items, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}"/>
```

**Option 2:**

Use [RelativeSource AncestorType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource) binding in your command.

Comment: I updated my question. I'm close but not quite there.