# Bind visibility of text box to view model property in a content template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

I am just trying to set a text box to collapsed in my GridViewColumnHeader.ContentTemplate. I believe everything is being done correctly but for some reason the text box won't collapse when the boolean property is set.

**Information**

- I have a View with a View Model that has a FilterRows boolean property.
- I am styling my grid view to allow users to set the FilterRows property and have filters for each header appear.
- I have tried using a BooleanToVisibilityConverter and a BooleanToCollapsedConverter.
- I have verified that the bool is being set in the view model when the user selects a check box.

**BooleanToCollapsedConverter**

This converter is in the same view as my grid view table. I know the converter works because I have used it on other UI elements in the same view.

```
   <Grid.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <local:BooleanToCollapsedConverter x:Key="BooleanToCollapsedConverter"/>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Grid.Resources>
```

This is the class for the booleanToCollapsedConverter

```
public class BooleanToCollapsedConverter : BaseValueConverter<BooleanToCollapsedConverter>
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**The View**

Here is a the code for a part of grid view column where I am trying to use the converter within the style. The GridViewColumnHeader visibility is being set properly and collapsing as needed. The inner portion with the data template is not working though.

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding Description}" 
                Width="auto">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content = "Description"
                          Visibility="{Binding HeaderList[1].IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToCollapsedConverter}}"
                          local:GridViewBehaviors.CollapseableColumn="True">
        <GridViewColumnHeader.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Height = "25" 
                             FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeSmall}" 
                             Visibility="{Binding FilterRows, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToCollapsedConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text = "Description" ></ TextBlock >
                </ StackPanel >
            </ DataTemplate >
        </ GridViewColumnHeader.ContentTemplate >
    </ GridViewColumnHeader >
</ GridViewColumn >
```

**The View Model**

This is my boolean property in the view model.

```
/// <summary>
    /// True if the user wants to apply filters to the rows.
    /// Once set the UI will display all filters
    /// </summary>
    public bool FilterRows
    {
        get => _filterRows;
        set => Set(ref _filterRows, value);
    }
```

[image]

**Final Points**

So overall I am just literally trying to collapse that text box when I check the Filter Rows: check box. Not sure if it has something to do with the style or I am doing something improperly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: the property `FilterRows` does not belong to each item of the `GridView`. it belongs to another object. so you need to specify what is the object that has `FilterRows` and then find a way to point the binding path towards that. e.g. using `x:static`, `RelativeSource`, implement `ParentViewModel`, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set data source for textbox binding. [How do I use WPF bindings with RelativeSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource)

smth like this. typeOfAncestor is UserControl or a Window

```
{Binding FilterRows, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToCollapsedConverter},
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}
```

Comment: I see what your saying. I tried using ancestor type of my page and it still did not work. The grid view is contained in a regular page. I have also tried using ancestor type of grid view and list view. (Grid view is in my list view). Still isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If the view model where the `FilterRows` property is defined is the `DataContext` of the parent `DataGrid`, this should work:

```
<TextBox Height="25" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeSmall}" 
                             Visibility="{Binding DataContext.FilterRows, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, 
                                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToCollapsedConverter}}"/>
```

Also note that there is a built-in converter for converting between `bool` and `Visibility` that you can use instead of creating your own one:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToCollapsedConverter" />
```