# Cannot Bind Grouping property in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, grouping

I have an `ObservableCollection` of items that I want to use to group my `ListView`, but I just can't bind my Grouping to that item.

That's my little class:

```
public class Module
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Module(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Module> ServerModules
{
    get => serverModules;
    set
    {
        if (serverModules == value) { return; }
        serverModules = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Here my Xaml Code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ServerModules}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Property" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="200"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DodgerBlue" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

The `Name` Property cannot be resolved.
I also tried using a `CollectionViewSource` but it's also not working for me:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupModules" Source="{Binding ServerModules}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupModules}}">
```

Any ideas and help are really appreciated.

**Update Solution:**
In my **Resources** section I defined a `CollectionViewSource` to set a GroupDescription property and a `Style` for my GroupItem.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedModules" Source="{Binding ServiceModuleSetViewModel.AllModuleProperties}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ModuleName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
    <!-- ListView GroupStyle.ContainerStyle -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="13" Foreground="DodgerBlue" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

ListView:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedModules}}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle/>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="local:ModuleProperty">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="local:ModuleProperty">
                            <TextBox FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" TextAlignment="Center"
                                     Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The `ListView` control has the `CollectionViewSource` Resource as `ItemsSource`.
Each `GridViewColumn` has a `CellTemplate` to display my data in the columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use WPF bindings with RelativeSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure - I tried something out, but still don't get the right result (see Update in Post). Maybe you can provide some code example.

Comment: Okay, I may have led you astray with my first comment.  I think this tutorial outlines pretty well how to use ListView grouping: [The ListView control: ListView grouping](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/)

Comment: That article definitely helped me, develope a solution. For me personally it was still hard to adapt the Code Behind examples from the website, to MVVM architecture, but finally I have a working solution. I will share it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define style for **GroupItem** or specify **GroupStyle.ContainerStyle**
Also for **GridViewColumn** you need to specify **DisplayMemberBinding**.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- ListView GroupStyle.ContainerStyle -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ServerModules}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle/>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Property" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" Width="200"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code example. For me that wasn't enough, I also needed to define a `CollectionViewSource` in the **Resources** section to be able to use a `GroupDescription` property. I will share my working solution above.