# Can I use XAML to create a binding between two DependencyProperties on the parent Page?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, winui-3

I have a `Page` called `HomePage` in a WinUI 3 Desktop App. `HomePage` has two `DependencyProperties`, `P1` and `P2`. I would like to create a binding that uses `P1` as the source and `P2` as the target (assume `P1` and `P2` are of the same type). This can be done easily in code but, can I create the binding in XAML?

This is the code for the binding:

```c#
public sealed partial class HomePage : Page
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Dependency property identifiers are static public fields. This is the identifier of the Target.
        var targetInfo = typeof(HomePage).GetField("P2Property", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (targetInfo is not null && targetInfo.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty))
        {
            Binding bBinding = new() { Path = new PropertyPath("P1"), Source=this, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };

            // this is a static field (there are no instance versions) and the value is the identifier of the DependencyProperty
            var dp = (DependencyProperty)targetInfo.GetValue(null);

            ClearValue(dp);
            SetBinding(dp, bBinding);       // create the binding
        }
    }

    // P1
    public static readonly DependencyProperty P1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "P1", typeof(object), typeof(HomePage), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object P1
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(P1Property);
        set => SetValue(P1Property, value);
    }

    // P2
    public static readonly DependencyProperty P2Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "P2", typeof(object), typeof(HomePage), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object P2
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(P2Property);
        set => SetValue(P2Property, value);
    }
}
```

Can the binding (`bBinding`) be created in XAML instead?

[Edit]
Thank you for the answers, which I have tried, but issues remain. Here is the XAML for HomePage:

```xaml
<Page
    x:Class="PFSI.Views.HomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="using:PFSI.Views"
    x:Name="homePage">

    <Grid>
        <!-- Blah -->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Defining the binding isn't the issue - any of: `P2="{Binding P1, ElementName=homePage}"`; `P2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=P1}"`;
or `P2="{x:Bind P1, Mode=OneWay}"` should work provided they can be applied to an element. `DataContext` is set to the `HomeViewModel` but that shouldn't matter here.

I tried using the suggested `<views:HomePage ... />` but the result is a stack overflow as the the compiler loops from the element to the class and back.

I thought a `Style` might work (something like:

```xaml
<Setter Property="P2" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=P1}"/>
```

) but `Setters` in WinUI 3 `Styles` don't support bindings (although, curiously, bindings work in `VisualStateManager` `Setters`).

I'm sure this should work in XAML - maybe it just needs to wait for `Setter` `Binding` support?

Comment: Try this `P2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:HomePage}}, Path=P1}"`

Comment: Thank you. Where in my XAML should I put this? Doesn't your clause need to be applied to some element?

Comment: There is no ``FindAncestor`` in WinUI 3 (at least for the moment).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3AppPageTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3AppPageTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <local:HomePage P2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=P1}"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**HomePage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3AppPageTest.HomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3AppPageTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextControl" Text="{x:Bind P1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind P2, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**HomePage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;

namespace WinUI3AppPageTest;

public sealed partial class HomePage : Page
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty P1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(P1),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(HomePage),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty P2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(P2),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(HomePage),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public HomePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string P1
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(P1Property);
        set => SetValue(P1Property, value);
    }

    public string P2
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(P2Property);
        set => SetValue(P2Property, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see edit, above. This results in stack overflow.

Comment: This works for me. I posted the all the related code.

Comment: Yes, I see, thanks. This code does bind P2 to P1 but it does it in the parent of the HomePage. The code version in the original post creates the binding whenever a HomePage is instantiated. I sort of envisioned HomePage.xaml as doing something equivalent (sort of the XAML constructor), not the parent. That's what I was originally asking but I may be able to get the result I want (which was for testing) using your approach when the page is loaded. Dang, Binding twists my mind :P

Answer (score 0):

This kind of binding is so-called self binding, which is used for binding to/between tag's own properties.

## 1 - Self-binding

Use `RelativeSourceMode.Self` to access tag's properties by specifying them in the `Path`property

```
<local:HomePage P2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=P1}"/>
```

Almost similar to Andrew's answer (explicit mode specification):

```
<local:HomePage P2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=P1}"/>
```

## 2 - ElementName

You can also try binding through `ElementName` if your layout contains multiple number of elements of the same type (or self):

```
<local:HomePage x:Name="MyHomePage" P2="{Binding ElementName=MyHomePage, Path=P1}"/>
```

## More

Explore more about `RelativeSource` and `Binding` markup extension to dive deep into it, coz it is really handy thing to use in your further projects.
Btw have a look at @james.lee [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67119194/14119764) on this topic.

Comment: Please see edit, above. These result in stack overflow.