# How to bind the Text property of a TextBlock from a different page

Tags: c#, xaml

I've looked it up but have found no solutions to my seemingly unique situation. I am trying to figure out how I would be able to bind and set a TextBlock text from within a different page.

**What I want to be able to do in ShellPage.xaml.cs**

```
SomeValue = "Some text...";
```

**Page2.xaml**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeValue}" Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" />
```

Comment: try to find it with ancestor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource or make sure your viewmodels share the text (property) somehow and bind each individually.

Comment: share the ViewModels can also work in UWP applications. Some introductions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#binding-object-declared-using-binding

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xname-directive) and a [FieldModifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xfieldmodifier-directive) attributes (from the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml` namespace, usually named "x") to the element you want to access, something like this:

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="MyText"
    x:FieldModifier="public"
    Text="{Binding SomeValue}"
    Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
/>
```

This will instruct the behind-the-scene-generator to generate a named item in your class and make it `public` in target language (here C#). This is an extract of the generated code:

```
partial class MainWindow : global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window
{
    ...
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.Compiler", " 1.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
      ...
    }

    ...
    public global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock MyText;
    ...
   
}
```

Now, if you have an instance of MainWindow, you can call its members.