How to set a different DataContext for a WPF datagrid column?
I'm using a DataGrid in my .NET 8 WPF app. The datagrid is set to a data context from a third-party library. I'd like to add a button column (as a DatagridTemplateColumn) to call a function in my own view model. I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.
I tried this:
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Map" DataContext="viewmodels:vmView1" Command="{Binding OpenMapCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

In my view model vmView1:
public ICommand OpenMapCommand { get; private set; }

public vmView1()
{
    OpenMapCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OpenMap);
}

Is this even possible?
Thanks.
Don

You could use a RelativeSource on the binding to find the DataContext of the Window See here for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource

Ryan, thanks for that. I'm looking to bind to an ICommand on the view model, so I tried this:
<Button Content="Map" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenMapCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:vmView1}}}"/>
Autocomplete finds the OpenMapCommand, but when I run it, I get a binding error because the data context is null. So I'm still missing something.

Ah, solved it. I have to reference the view, not the view model. Duh.
